# Need Help getting started with Visual Studio to use C# and ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-express

I am trying to learn web application development using C# and ASP.net. I have experience with PHP and MySQL and I am having a hard time relating to the Visual Studio Express way of doing things. I supposedly have access to a .NET server.

I can upload a file called `test.aspx` and this code seems to work. I am calling this "Classic Mode ASP with C#"

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
   <% for (int i=0; i <6; i++) { %>
      <font size="<%=i%>"> I don't want the world, I just want your half </font> <br>
   <% }
   Response.Write("<p><cite>They Might Be Giants - Ana Ng</cite>");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try and use ASP: controls with the following code and upload with FTP

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="HelloWorld2.aspx">
<asp:TextBox id="sentence" maxlength=100 width=200px runat=server />
<br>
<input runat="server" type=submit value="Submit" ID="submit" NAME="submit"><br>


<% if (Request.QueryString["submit"] != null) {
      for (int i=0; i <6; i++) { %>
      <font size="<%=i%>"> <%=Request.QueryString["sentence"]%></font> <br>
      <% }
   }%>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The page breaks.

When I try to use Visual Studio to create a page, build and deploy my pages break also. It seems that when ever I try even simple code with a control like:

```
<asp:TextBox id="sentence" maxlength=100 width=200px runat=server />
```

The page breaks.

Here is the error I get:

> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a `<customErrors>` tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This `<customErrors>` tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
 <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->  
 <configuration>  
    <system.web>  
       <customErrors mode="Off"/>  
    </system.web>  
 </configuration>
```

> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's `<customErrors>` configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
 <!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->  
 <configuration>  
    <system.web>  
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>  
    </system.web>  
 </configuration>
```

I have tried talking to the hosting company and they are not being very helpful. They can't get it to work and tell me that they can't provide support for application code. I have told them that I just want to make sure the asp.net controls work if they could test it then I would be on my way... still like trying to pull teeth.

As a follow up questions... what Microsoft software should I / could I use to manage the SQL Server that I have access to? I would like to build the database in an application that assists instead of writing it by hand.

Comment: Did you do what the error said and open web.config and add the specified tags?

Comment: You should still be able to edit the web.config file so that the real error gets displayed, as the current message explains. This will get you at least this far.

Comment: You wouldn't be getting that error page if you tried building and running your web page in Visual Studio.  Why in the world would you keep deploying code to a web hosting site without testing it locally first?

Comment: As a side note, since you're just starting with asp.net and you are coming from php, you may find it easier to pick up asp.net mvc, since you'll work directly with html instead of server controls.

Comment: Also, instead of `runat=server`, try `runat="server"`. Everything should be in quotes. Same thing with `MaxLength` and `Width`

Comment: For your database question, I use [SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062). Its free!

Comment: Rick, I did run it locally and it worked fine. Build then deployed

Comment: OK I started editing the web config and that is where the problem is.. the web config has a bunch of other settings that were breaking and that is what the errors - off showed me... members providers etc... I ripped all of that out and just added the code that you all provided and the page displayed... still not 100% yet but I think I will be there in a second.

Comment: Ok it seems that the server hates the config file... its breaking on every line. When I get it to go onto the page it breaks on the first line saying that the site.master can't befound... its there.... I am just trying to deploy the default page when you create a website project

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you do a few things here.

The first is, research this more rather than diving in.  Check out sites like www.asp.net and www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com.  If you have experience with other web platforms, you might only need a few hours of research to get this all clicking.

Secondly, can you run the application locally?  If you use F5 (Run), does the application compile without errors and run?

Thirdly, your issue "might" be that you need to publish your web application, rather than just copying files.  In Visual Studio, right click the web application, choose publish, and follow the prompts.  This will compile the application and copy up the appropriate files.

Fourthly, look for the "CustomErrors" setting in the web.config file, located in your web root.  There, uncomment the "customErrors" tag if HTML commented out, and set the mode to "Off".  That will cause the actual server error to display in your web browser.  Once you get that error, update your question with those details, and im sure we can help you out more.

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: 1) I have taken a C# class and did very well in it. But it was window application based.
<br>
2) I can run the application locally just fine.

3) I went through the build process and published the site using visual studio by right clicking on the website solution name. The site now shows up on the One Click Publish tool bar.

4) I don't have access to the webconfig but I will work on getting that update. It was working for a min while talking to the hosting company but he reset it I think.

Comment: I agree with @ewitkows , research ASP.NET before you dive in. ASP.NET differs a lot from Classic ASP. We also do things differently when compared to PHP. learnvisualstudio.com is a great site (not free) if you're considering a career in .NET technologies, it will be a good investment. Otherwise, www.asp.net and tutorials around the web will help you get started.

Comment: Thanks @Onebigcelt, ASP.NET with C# and Winforms with C# are 2 different animals, so no insult intended, was just trying to help you understand the publish model and website lifecycle some.  You can update the web.config in Visual Studio and publish that way, it's possible you don't have direct access to the config file on the server, but you can publish your config changes locally.  Once you get the site running, if you hit any errors, go ahead and post those error messages, the SO community is always happy to help :)

Comment: You guys are awesome. I have been trying to get co-workers to help me break this barrier but its been hard. The staff here is married to coldfusion.... they want to go to .net but there are no .net programers here. lol

Answer (score 1):

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

That will show you the error.  Update your web.config.

Answer (score 0):

When you FTP your code to your server, you have Web.config file in it. Modify the Web.config as it says in your error. Change to

```
<customErrors mpde ="Off" ... />
```

That will show you the errors. Make sure to revert your changes when you're done.

For the Database question: Open your Project, in View -> Server Explorer you will be able to add your Database and Manage from that window.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking it was at the Server level

Comment: Almost anything that you can do with T-SQL can be done this way.